# Await a function in a functional component

Tags: reactjs

I have a functional component that renders an image, I'm getting a `File` prop as a child and needs to convert it to a `dataUri` for the image source, however I'm not sure how to `await` within a non-async function.

```
 const toBase64 = file =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result)
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error)
  })

export default function Print({item}) {
  const classes = useStyles({})

  const dataUri = await toBase64(item.photo) //can't use wait here

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.imgContainer}>
        {dataUri && <img className={classes.img} src={dataUri.toString()} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: when you have an async call you should use useEffect hook and you can pass the second argument as the dependent prop as an array, so if any of the prop changes only it will call, if you doesn't pass array as second argument it will call after every render and if you pass an empty array it will call only one time like componentDidMount life cycle .. Hope this will give a better understanding of the pblm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and move the logic to `useEffect` callback:

```
const toBase64 = file =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });

export default function Print({ item }) {
  const [dataUri, setDataUri] = useState();
  const classes = useStyles({});

  useEffect(async () => {
    const dataUriFetched = await toBase64(item.photo);
    setDataUri(dataUriFetched);
  }, [item]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.imgContainer}>
        {dataUri && <img className={classes.img} src={dataUri.toString()} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please ask another question because it's out of scope, also you didn't tag the current question with TS and there is not TS code in here

Answer (score 0):

As recommended in React docs, I ended up doing the below-

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchDataUri() {
      const dataUriFetched = await toBase64(item.photo)
      setDataUri(dataUriFetched)
    }
    fetchDataUri()
  }, [item])
```

Answer (score -1):

You would have to make your function async. Like so:

```
export default async function Print({item}) {
  const classes = useStyles({})

  const dataUri = await toBase64(item.photo) //can't use wait here

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.imgContainer}>
        {dataUri && <img className={classes.img} src={dataUri.toString()} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now you should be able to use await without any problems.